# Inserting javascript into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, insert

A have a wordpress chat site, the chat is hosted external. They have a few php files i can call to access a list of users online etc.

for example opening `http://www.chatservice.com/mysite/logged_users.php` in a browser outputs. `document.write('4');` So i use the below script to display this on my front page.

```
<div id="A">
    <script src="http://chatservice.com/mysite/logged_users.php"></script>
</div>
```

However, sometimes the chat goes offline and that script prevents the rest of my site loading. So I thought id try load into the div from the footer. No luck. I did manage to get it working by from the footer by loading into an iframe though

```
$("#my_iframe").attr("src", "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + 
"There are " +
"<script src=\"http://chatservice.com/mysite/logged_users.php\"><" + "/script>" +
" people chatting"
);
```

However, that wont work in internet explorer 11! :-(

Does any one here have any idea how to insert

```
<script src="http://chatservice.com/mysite/logged_users.php"></script>
```

From the footer into the main content? that works with all the latest browsers? Been trying hours lol.

Thank you.

Comment: It is the first time in my life I see an HTML `<script>` tag pointing to a PHP script.  Someone to explain to me please? I am interested to understand how

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers lol... perhaps he is echoing JS from the PHP script?

Comment: have you used JSONP?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better if you use ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://chatservice.com/mysite/logged_users.php",
    cache: false
})

.done(function(html) {
    $("#logged_users").append(html);
});
```

and the file `logged_users.php` should only echo `4`

Comment: thanks. I have no control over logged_users.php :) thats hosted externally